# Stting a state causes infinite loop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving data from firebase realtime db and storing it in array called userrs and using that array to set "post". But line "setPost(users);  " is causing infinite loop. Can anyone point out my mistake.

```
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
    let users = [];
    const starCountRef = ref(db);
    get(child(starCountRef, "post")).then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          snapshot.forEach(
            function(childSnapshot){
                users.push(childSnapshot.val()); 
            }  
          ) 
            setPost(users);  
        } else {
          console.log("post");
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });      
      console.log(post);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `setPost(users)` inside the `get` function which will trigger a re-render of the component making a infinite loop.

Try moving your `get` function inside a `useEffect` hook.
This will make it only run once when the component mounts.

```
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const starCountRef = ref(db);
  get(child(starCountRef, "post")).then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      const users = [];
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        users.push(childSnapshot.val()); 
      });
      setPost(users);  
    } else {
      console.log("post");
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}, []);
```